# SSL certificate creation

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl

When i created self signed certificate , my company told like this will not be accepted and they gave certificate like how we are getting from CA, like verisign or Godaddy, but that is a .cer file. How can i upload a .cer file in IIS? if i remember correctly  we can upload .pfx file only in IIS.IF this is the case how can i convert company given .cer file in to .pfx? do we need to give server name as fully qualified name?
When i was creating self signed one i used mkcert.exe to create .cer file and pvk tool to generate .pfx file, pvk tool is sufficient to generate pfx file or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert your cert and you can use openssl to achieve the conversion that you are wanting.

For instance:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey cert.key -in cert.crt
```

Comment: You should install openssl.

Comment: can i use pvk tool for this?